# How to get the paths of files in sub directories that contain specific string in a directory python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a directory that contains few sub directories. In each sub directory there are few files, and I'd like to get the full paths of the files that contain the word "raw" in their filename and that ends with ".txt" (in each directory there is a file with "raw" in it's name).

Anyone knows how to do it elegantly with python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [`Path.resolve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) method to get the absolute path to the directory, then use [`Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to collect the `Path` objects representing the paths of the files we want to retrieve.

```
from pathlib import Path

paths = [path for path in Path('path/to/dir').resolve().glob("**/*raw*.txt")]
```

Here your search is specified by `**/*raw*.txt`.  This will return some number of `Path` objects (the exact type will depend on the operating system you use).
  If you want them as strings, you can substitute `[str(path) for path in ..]` above